# Threaded BlockingQueue, clarification needed

Tags: java, multithreading

When working with a `BlockingQueue`, i implemented the following logic to **read from it until told otherwise**. Unfortunately the following is happening, intermittently:

The problem:

- Even after shouldContinueReading is set to false, loop does not CONSISTENTLY break
- The problem is intermittent, sometimes everything works fine

As part of the QThread class, i declare:

```
public static volatile boolean          shouldContinueReading   = true;
```

Run (confirmed to be executing) method contains:

```
    while (shouldContinueReading) {
        try {

            String retrieved = qIn.poll(2, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            if (retrieved != null)
                consume(retrieved);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    System.out.println("I am out");  // <-- not always seen
    if (qIn.remainingCapacity() > 0) {
        try {
            consume(qIn.take());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

While this is going on, in another thread, when certain things happen, `shouldContinueReading` changes state

```
    while (stillReading) {
        // do nothing
    }

    QThread.shouldContinueReading = false;
```

### Update: problem resolved

Turns out the problem lies a bit further:

```
private void consume(String take) {
            // some processing

    produce(newData.toString());
}

private void produce(String newData) {
    System.out.println(newData);
    try {
        qOut.put(newData);          // <-- Problem is here. Should use offer instead of put
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Both qIn (queue in) and qOut (queue out) are declared as:

```
private volatile BlockingQueue<String>  qIn;
private volatile BlockingQueue<String>  qOut;
```

The objects themselves are created elsewhere as follows and passed down to the constructor:

```
    BlockingQueue<String> q1 = new SynchronousQueue<String>();
    BlockingQueue<String> q2 = new SynchronousQueue<String>();

    QThread qThread = new QThread(q1, q2);
```

Any suggestions? what i should do with qOut? Am i not declaring it correctly?

Comment: Is 'shouldContinueReading' declared as volatile?

Comment: @JAM: are you *sure* you're checking *shouldContinueReading*?  If you are sure, is *shouldContinueReading* volatile?  Because if it isn't *volatile*, then nothing guarantees that modificating that boolean from another thread shall make the modification visible to your thread here...

Comment: Considering there's nowhere in that code that `shouldContinueReading` is set to `false` ... no idea.

Comment: @MitchWheat It is not .. let me try. `shouldContinueReading` is a `public static` variable set to false outside of this `Thread`

Comment: @JAM Since you haven't posted the whole code it is a bit difficult to say... but maybe the problem is also the modification visibility of `stillReading`.

Comment: Are you sure the second thread gets run? It could be that the "shouldContinueReading" could be taking up the CPU time and not letting the other thread run and mark the boolean as false. You could try a Thread.yield() to make sure that other threads get the chance to mark shouldContinueReading as false

Comment: @UsmanIsmail Yes, I have tried and confined that indeed `run()` method is being executed

Comment: You know that `put()` on a `SynchronousQueue` will block until another thread is waiting to take the element, right? What thread is doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet `QThread.shouldContinueReading = false;` isn't getting executed always,or the reading thread is not executing in the first place. I.e. the problem you are seeing is likely somewhere up the stream -- not here. The first thing I'd do would be to pin down where exactly the problem lies, with 100% confidence (put some more print statements).

Apart from the problem, I'd recommend to use the thread interruption mechanism instead of rolling your own flag (which is, in turn just a glorified flag, but that way you can affect third party codes like `BlockedQueue` and make the implementation simpler and more efficient even) especially if this is production code.

Comment: Could you provide an example of how thread interruption should work?